# inner join on true

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

My table:

```
   abc
+--------+
| letter |
+--------+
| a      |
| b      |
+--------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc t1 INNER JOIN abc t2
ON true
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+
| letter | letter |
+--------+--------+
| a      | a      |
| b      | a      |
| a      | b      |
| b      | b      |
+--------+--------+
```

What does or how does `ON true` do/work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I've never seen this exact syntax (for obvious reasons - it really serves little purpose and I wouldn't expect to encounter it in the real world) my guess would be that the result will be a cartesian product as the condition states that rows in t1 should be matched with rows in t2 when condition evaluates as true, which it always does. So all rows in the first set will be matched to all rows in the second set.

The condition is never tried against anything else, just itself and `true` will always evaluate as true.

Comment: I feel the same, INNER JOIN and ON true are redundant. ON true is implied.

Comment: in sql are the falsy values null and false?

Comment: @ThinkCode Indeed, the result should be the same as a `cross join`.

Comment: @RobertRocha The query never matches `true` against any column, just itself. And `true` is true. It's the same as using `1=1` which is quite common.

Comment: @RobertRocha Good question though; I've seen several of your previous questions and really like the methodical and thorough approach you take in learning the finer points. More people should do that :)

Comment: @jpw thanks. I like to break things down into simple units. I try different queries, modify queries and ask questions as I go.

Comment: Use cross join if Cartesian product is the intention